# Substitute of iframe (external dynamic page url open) in respect to Jquerymobile

Tags: android, html, android-layout, android-emulator, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuerymobile with HTML5, but i want to open a external dynamic page(url) in a DIV on my page layout without using JQM dialog property which should work on all smart devices (Android,iOS,BB, Symbain, MeeGO, Bada)

Help will be much appricated

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement but after going down the path and demoing several versions opening a page in an iframe the problem is two part:

It works but it is extremely buggy. I have found that working with an iframe on a page really is not friendly at all. You will need to modify the viewport size among other things which is a meta tag that gets set in jquery mobile. Even after that trying to pinch and zoom just is clumsy.

Are you trying to load the page with ajax into the div from like a 3rd party external site?

Comment: Ya kind of 3ed party , for example in a div LHS i want to open a google.com page or some html page. so how will i open that page using JQM without any iframe